# How can I not allow the user to continue entering any input in textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a Q&A in one of my websites and I wanted to assign a 100-word limit. I created a short JS function that pops up a message that says that the input is too long but I also want it to stop allowing the user to continue writing. What line of code can I add to stop allowing the user to type in more than 100 words?
In the following lines I will post the JS function and the HTML of the Q&A.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <title>Oversimplified</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        
    </style>
    
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../styles.css' />
</head>

<body id='Q-A-BG'>
    <header class="Header Subsection"> <!-- This is the menu-->
        <nav class="Header-Container">
            <button class="hamburgerMenu">
              <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="menu w-6 h-6">
                <path
                  fill-rule="evenodd"
                  d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
                  clip-rule="evenodd"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </button>
            <ul id="MobileMenu" class="Menu SubsectionMenu">
              <li><a href="../Oversimplified.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="Q&A.html">Q&A</a></li>
              <li><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
              <!-- <li><button class="themeToggle">Theme</button></li> -->
            </ul>
          </nav>
    </header>
    <article class="Questions"><!--This has to do with the Information section-->
        <h1> Submit your question</h1>
        <form method='GET' action='mailto:wot.questionsanswers@gmail.com' enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="InputSection">
                <label for='first-name'> First name</label>
                <input id='first-name' name='body' type='text' placeholder="First Name" required/> 
            </div>
            <div class="InputSection">
                <label for='last-name'> Last name</label>
                <input id='last-name' name='body' type='text' placeholder="Last Name" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="InputSection">
                <label for='Education'>Level of education</label>
                <select id='Education' name='Education'>
                    <option></option>
                    <option>High School</option>
                    <option>Physics undergraduate</option>
                    <option>Physics graduate</option>
                    <option>Adult with little knowledge of physics</option>
                    <option>Adult with some knowledge of physics</option>
                    <option>Adult with college level knowledge of physics</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="InputSection">
                <label for='subject'> Subject</label>
                <input id='subject' name='subject' placeholder='Subject' required/>
            </div>
            <div class="InputSection">
                <label for='question'> Your question</label>
                <textarea id='question' name='body' placeholder="Be precise and describe your question in less than 100 words" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <p class="longQuestion">
                Please enter a question in less than 100 words
            </p>
            <div class="InputSection">
                <label class='Checkbox' for='accepts'>
                <input id='accepts' name='accepts' type='checkbox' value='Agrees to the terms' required/>
                <span> I accept the <a href="#"> Terms and Conditions</a></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="InputSection">
                <input id='SubmitButton' type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </article>
<script src="../wordLimit.js"></script>
<script src="../hamburgerMenu.js"></script>
<script src="../darkMode.js"></script>
</body>

</html> 

/*100 word limit*/
const question = document.querySelector("#question");
const errorMessage = document.querySelector(".longQuestion");

function lessThan100() {
    const questionWords = question.value.split(" ");
    if (questionWords.length > 100) {
        errorMessage.style.display = "block";
        question.style.border = "1px solid red";
    } else {
        errorMessage.style.display = "none";
        question.style.border = "1px solid black";
    }
}
      
question.addEventListener("input", lessThan100);
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML please ?

Comment: Sure, added it already

Comment: If your question is solved - consider marking any of the solutions that helped you the most you as answered by clicking the **grey checkmark** in an answer so others can see what helped in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After sending the error message, simply reset questionWords;

`question.value = questionWords.slice(0, 100).join(" ");`

Comment: I do not want to erase what we wrote, simply not allow him to write anymore

Comment: @Aaron_Serpilin that's what this does, it erases everything past 100 words, effectively preventing the user from writing anymore.

Comment: Ok, I just tested it. It doesn't allow me to write another word because I can't use space. How can I tweak it to not allow me to type in any other character?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` with the `keydown` event:

```js
document.getElementById('limit').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (this.value.split(/\s+/).length > 100 && !['ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'ArrowUp', 'ArrowDown', 'Backspace'].includes(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault()
    document.getElementById('limitWarning').innerHTML = 'You have reached the 100 word limit'
  } else {
    document.getElementById('limitWarning').innerHTML = ''
  }
})
```

```html
<input id='limit' placeholder='Max 100 words'>
<div id='limitWarning'></div>
```

Comment: using `e.preventDefault()` is not a option here since it is consider bad for UX.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping But, it could be adapted to show a warning

Answer (score 0):

For better **UX** (user experience) you need to disable the `textarea` as soon it reaches the word limit. This way the user will know that they can not type anymore.

We need to visually show the user that the 100 words limit is reached. So that's why using `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` is not a good method here.

We can use the [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) property of input element by setting it to `true` or `false`

In addition, Using this method you do **not** need to change your current `code` and keep it as it is.

**Edit:**

Also if you need more `strict` checking, add `focusin` event to your `question` element.

Currently it splits words with single space, if you don't care if user put more than one space between words, you can use `/\s+/g` instead of single space.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
/*100 word limit*/
const question = document.querySelector("#question");
const errorMessage = document.querySelector(".longQuestion");

function lessThan100() {
  const questionWords = question.value.split(' ');
  
  // for multiple space between words,
  // uncomment code below and comment first one
//  const questionWords = question.value.split(/\s+/g);
  
  console.log(questionWords);

  if (questionWords.length > 5) {
    errorMessage.style.display = "block";
    question.style.border = "1px solid red";
    question.disabled = true
  } else {
    errorMessage.style.display = "none";
    question.style.border = "1px solid black";
    question.disabled = false
  }
}

question.addEventListener("input", lessThan100);

// for more strict checking
question.addEventListener("focusin", lessThan100);
```

```html
<textarea id="question" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea>
<div class="longQuestion">
  Can not write more then 5 words
</div>
```

Comment: You have to change the split value to `/\s+/g` for it to cope with multiple spaces - https://prnt.sc/ucozl3